# Django rest framework update ManyToManyField

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gamemodes = models.ManyToManyField(GameMode, related_name='gamemodes', blank=True)

class GameMode(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class GameModeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ['pk', 'name']
        model = GameMode

class GameSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    
    gamemodes = GameModeSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['pk', 'name', 'gamemodes']
     
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print("Validated: ", validated_data)
```

Updating name works perfectly with PATCH. But how can I add a "gamemode" to the Game object in the rest framework with a PATCH request?

On the update function on the serializer, it print all values when I PATCH something, but when I submit "gamemodes" it does not appear in the variable **validated_data**

Best

Comment: Have you tried what's listed in the documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers?

Comment: Problem is that "gamemodes" is not added to validated_data

Comment: What data you submitting for `gamemodes`?

Comment: @schillingt [1,]

Answer (score 1):

With your current serializer setup you need to supply the dicts for `gamemodes`.

```
{
    "pk": 1,
    "name": "Game 1",
    "gamemodes": [{"pk": 100, "name": "gamemode 100"}]
}
```

Alternatively you could add to your GameSerializer to also have a write only field that accepts the pks for the relationship [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) or [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) if you don't want to use the internal ids.